# Кросс-доменный запрос ASP.NET WebApi и Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Доброго времени суток!
Не первый день бьюсь над задачей, не могу понять в чем причина.

Хочу создать почти HelloWorld решение, для обмена информацией между клиентом и сервером посредством Angular (разные адреса ресурсов).

Серверная часть, стандартная функция (как ValuesController) для метода GET и POST, контроллер требует авторизации.

Клиентская часть, страница регистрации и авторизации и страница получения данных (метод GET) и страница отправки данных (метод POST).

В конфигурации сервера указал разрешение для соединения:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:16174" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Метод для GET выглядит проще некуда:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "GET1", "GET2" };
}
```

и для POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<string> Post()
{
    return new string[] { "POST_Param1", "POST_Param2" };
}
```

У контроллера атрибут Authorize.

Клиентская часть:

```
var serverAddress = "serverAddr";
var app = angular.module('appHello');

app.controller("controllerHello", [
    "$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {

        var token = sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey);

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: serverAddress + '/api/EmployeeAPI',
            headers: { 'authorization': 'bearer ' + token }
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.cash = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.error("Connect error");
        });
    }
]);
```

Результат запроса:

> Request:
>
> OPTIONS /api/EmployeeAPI HTTP/1.1
>  Connection: keep-alive
>   Pragma: no-cache
>  Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/55.0.2883.35 Safari/537.36
>  Access-Control-Request-Headers:
>   authorization
>  Accept: */*
>  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate,
>   sdch, br
>  Accept-Language:
>   ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>
> Response:
>
> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
>  Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>  Allow: GET
>  Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8
>  Expires: -1
>  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>  X-SourceFiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU2l0ZXNcVGVzdFxUZXN0U2RcU291cmNlXFNlcnZlclxhcGlcRW1wbG95ZWVBUEk=?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,
>   authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
>  Date: Wed, 09 Nov 2016
>   18:59:34 GMT
>  Content-Length: 108

Ответ сервера:

```
{"Message":"Запрошенный ресурс не поддерживает HTTP-метод "OPTIONS"."}
```

Проблема заключается в том что не могу понять почему отправляется кросс-доменный запрос OPTIONS а обоих случаях что GET что POST а не GET или POST.
Если свои заголовки не подключать (authorization для передачи токена) то запрос корректно уходит.

Что я делаю не так, в чем проблема?

[image: WebKit]
[image: WebKit]